# JDBC Connectivity : Data Direct ODBC Drivers

Tags: jdbc

I have to use the ODBC drivers by Data Direct in java program.
`Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );

          c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:"+ODBC_DSN, username, password );`

One of the existing C++ program uses the same drivers and after the connection they set the License details  via UTLSQLSetConnectOption

Can you suggest what would be the equivalent in Java.

Comment: what do you mean? what do you want to acomplish?

Comment: If i run the program via Oracle Drivers, it works fine. But if run the with Data Direct ODBC driver, connnection happens but error comes while executing any sql statements. One of the C++ program faced similar issue in the past and after connection, they set the License key and password and it works. I have to implement the same in Java.